# Execution Affecting Already Set Timeouts

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout

I am pretty experienced in Javascript but I have come across a weird issue in developing a web app where the script just isn't behaving as it should be. Oddly (inexplicably, in fact) I don't experience this issue when I am using my offline development copy or after logging in. However, when the user is already logged in and they refresh the page, they come across this issue.

Here is the affected method (this is literally the entire thing):

```
_setLiveSyncTimeout: function (firstTestCall) {
    if (firstTestCall) {
        console.log('set next')
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(200, 'a');
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                console.log(400, 'b');
            }, 200);
        }, 200);

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(400, 'c');
        }, 400);
    }

    this._liveSyncTimeout = setTimeout(_(this.liveSyncNow).bind(this), this._liveSyncPeriod);
}
```

I noticed that `this.liveSyncNow` didn't seem to be getting called every time I would have expected it too, so I added in the if statement above to debug. Weirdly, when you pass in `true`, the first timeout ('a') will run, however, the 'b' and 'c' do not. Since the result of `setTimeout` is not stored in these cases, it should be literally impossible to cancel them but, for no apparent reason, they simply do not run. In the same case that 'b' and 'c' do not run, the timeout for `this.liveSyncNow` does not run either.

From tests it appears that when this function runs, all of the timeouts previously created in it get cancelled. The reason that the 'a' timeout does run is that there is a 200ms gap between the call where it is created and the next one.

**Edit**

This occurs in at least Chrome and Firefox.

**Edit 2**

Here is a more simple example of the issue. This is part of the definition of a Backbone model (you don't need to worry about that though). This is literally the entire function.

```
initialize: function () {
    var a = setInterval(function () {
        console.log('test')
    }, 50);
}
```

The setInterval runs three times ('test' appears in the console three time) and then just stops.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, please add a complete sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Maybe `setTimeout` method is being modified. I mean something like this `window.setTimeout = function() {}`

Comment: @Zub I did consider that. I did `console.log(setTimeout)` and it was unchanged [native code].

Comment: @RobW I cannnot really give a complete sample since that would be an entire 25000 line program. I don't think it would really help. Evidently, from the above code, the problem isn't actually the program itself.

Comment: Since `clearTimeout` takes first parameter as integer (number of `setTimeout` call), maybe you are accidentally clearing `setTimeout` by passing a wrong integer in some other place?

Comment: if you use set timeout and Dont use a variable to record the handle returned by set timeout, the JS interpreter uses a default handle, which gets re-used each time you use set timeout.  I'd need to look up the docs on MDN to be 100% sure of the intricies , but the resolution is to use 'var abc = setTimeout....' then 'var def = settimeout....' and so on, even if you don't actually plan to do anything with the data.

Comment: @shawty why would that cause an issue?

Comment: @Zub worth considering... I will take a look at my code.

Comment: @Zub I logged `this._liveSyncTimeout` once it had been set. I then logged the id passed into every single `clearTimeout` in my code. However, the same id never came up. The timeout is just stopped for no reason.

Comment: @shawty I still experience this issue with `this._liveSyncTimeout` in spite of assigning the id to a variable (also see my above comment to zub)

Comment: Try to write `window.clearTimeout = function() {}` before any other script on your page. How will it behave in this case?

Comment: @Zub you're a clever bastard. I modded `window.clearTimeout` to through an error whenever it tried to clear that timeout. I tracked that back in the stack to a particular dodgy function, which I will now fix. Thanks a lot. For what its worth, I was wrong to blame the browser.

Comment: I'm glad you've found an answer )

Comment: @zub from what I remember when I read about it, if you call a settimeout straight after another it stops the previous one and starts a new instance due to it using a default inbuilt variable. When you use vars externally however it uses those so there's no corruption.  In this case however it doesn't appear to have had any effect.  I'll need to have a dig and find the previous docs. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experience this issue (unsurprisingly) as a totally unrelated piece of code was incorrectly cancelling my timeouts. This happened because I was using a modded version of `setTimeout`, which returned its own incrementally-assigned integer but I did not use the correct modded version of `clearTimeout` and instead used the original `window.clearTimeout`. As a result my good timers were incorrectly being cancelled.

I found this issue and tracked down the dodgy piece of code by overwriting `clearTimeout` and finding out who called it, when, and with what id.

I have attempted to prevent this from happening in future by assigning ids in my modded `setTimeout` decrementally, below 0.